# Playing videos from terminal

Tags: 14.04, command-line, video, gnome-terminal, vlc

I am trying to play videos from terminal using this command

```
vlc my_video.avi
```

The error that I am getting when I try to run the command--

```
VLC media player 2.1.4 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4-0-g2a072be)
[0x8663910] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use    vlc without interface.
[0xaafddf80] filesystem access error:cannot open file the_file_path (no such file or directory)
[0xb040a990] main input error:open of 'file://the_file_path' failed
```

Then I tried to use 'cvlc' but again same error!

Comment: Quick test using "VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28)" on 14.04 release has no problem when running `vlc file.mp4` in Terminal. Probably something wrong with the file path?

Answer (score 1):

Try install mplayer

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer
```

and run

```
mplayer -vo caca <movie_file
```

and check whether you are able to play the video

Answer (score 1):

There must be something wrong with your filename. I tried two things.

1. `vlc wrongfileName.mp4` and it gave me the error you described.
2. `vlc correctFileName.mp4` this one gave different error output, but the file did open, so I suspect you made a typo or need to quote the path if it has spaces or special characters

second error for reference:

```
navjeet@navjeet-Lenovo-G50-80:~/Videos/Game Of Thrones GOT/Season 2$
vlc Game.of.Thrones.S02E08.HDTV.x264-ASAP.mp4 VLC media player 2.2.2
Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80) [000000000141a148] core libvlc:
Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface. 
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_va_gl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_va_gl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory [00007f6b74000ee8] http access error: error:
HTTP/1.1 522 Origin Connection Time-out [00007f6b840019d8] http access error: error: HTTP/1.1 522 Origin Connection Time-out [00007f6b74000ee8] core access error: connection failed: Network is unreachable [00007f6b74000ee8] core access error: connection failed:
Network is unreachable [00007f6b74000ee8] http access error: cannot connect to services.tvrage.com:80
```

Comment: @Zanna thanks for formatting :) . You have made it very  presentable.

Comment: Any time :) thanks for contributing to the site

Answer (score 1):

why did no one suggest `totem`, which is preinstalled? ^^

```bsh
cd /path/to/location/of/video
totem video.mp4
```

Answer (score -2):

This is easy :

```
playername video_or_audio_file_name
```

And you should not be under root.

Comment: -1 because OP has already mentioned that `vlc my_video.avi` (playername filename) doesn't work.